# What do I need as assumptions on $f$ to get $P(X \in A) = P (f(X) \in f(A))$ for a (probability) measure $P$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Good day,

In class we had a problem where we used the property

$$P(|X_n| > \epsilon ) = P\left(\frac{|X_n|}{1+|X_n|} > \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \right)$$

and said that this holds since $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is strictly increasing.

I don't really know why so my general question is:

> What do I need as assumptions on $f$ to get $P(X \in A) = P (f(X) \in f(A))$ for a (probability) measure $P$? And why exactly?

Maybe this holds for a general measure so I put "probability" in brackets.

I should need sth like this: $$P(f(X) \in f(A))=P(X \in f^{-1}(f(A))=P(X \in A)$$
i.e. $f$ should be left-invertible (please say whether this is enough). But I am still not convinced that I can do this inside of $P$, seems quite sketchy/rigorous to me.

So let's prove

> $P(f(X)\in A)=P(X \in f^{-1}(A))$

Let $\mu_Y$ denote the distribution of a random variable $Y$ via $\mu_Y(A)=P(Y \in A)$. Then

$$P(f(X) \in A)= \int_A \mu_{f(X)}(dx) \color{red}{=} \int_{f^{-1}(A)} \mu_{X}(dx)=P(X \in f^{-1}(A))$$

where I am not sure about "$\color{red}{=}$". Can someone please fill this step for me?

Thanks a lot,
Marvin

Comment: "So let's prove..." In general $f(x)\in A\iff x\in f^{-1}(A)$ and from this it follows immediately that $P(f(X)\in A)=P(X\in f^{-1}(A))$

Comment: @drhab Yeah, I also saw this after you have proved in your answer $x \in A \Rightarrow ...$ .
I should think more in these set relations where I can use known algebra of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general: $$A\subseteq f^{-1}f(A)$$

This because $$x\in A\implies f(x)\in f(A)\implies x\in f^{-1}f(A)$$

Consequently:$$P(X\in A)\leq P(X\in f^{-1}(f(A)))=P(f(X)\in f(A))$$

If $f$ is injective (left-invertible is the same) then: $$A= f^{-1}f(A)$$ for every set $A$.

---

Extreme case: $f$ is a constant function.

Then for every non-empty $A$ we have $\{f(X)\in f(A)\}=\Omega$ and consequently $P(f(X)\in f(A))=1$.

But if $X$ is not degenerated then we can find non-empty sets $A$ with $P(X\in A)<1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, clears a lot for me. One question: Does $$P(X\in A)\leq P(X\in f^{-1}f(A))$$
work since $P$ is a positive measure and we integrate on a larger set (speaking informally) on the right side since $A \subset f^{-1} f(A)$?

Comment: It works because $\{X\in A\}\subseteq\{X\in f^{-1}(f(A))\}$ wich is a direct consequence of $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$. As you know probability measures are monotone: $A\subseteq B\implies P(A)\leq P(B)$

Comment: As a question to your remark below. What does it mean for a RV $X$ to be degenerated? I didn't hear it in this context up to now.

Comment: It means that $P(X=c)=1$ for some constant $c$. If that is the case then $P(X\in A)\in\{0,1\}$ for every measurable $A$.

Comment: Might be overkill but can I prove this via Kolmogorovs $0$-$1$-law? For this I have to prove that $\{ X \in A \}$ is in the tail-$\sigma$-algebra. But I think the situation is a bit different since there I have independent sequence of RVs $X_n$ and an event $A \in \cap_n \sigma (X_i, i\geq n)$. Then $P(A) \in \{0,1 \}$.

Comment: No Kolmogorov for this, it is basic stuff. If $P(X=c)=1$ then $P(X\in A)=0$ if $c\notin A$ and $P(X\in A)=1$ if $c\in A$.

Comment: I could take a constant sequence $X=X_i$ for all $i$. Then $\cap \sigma(X_i, i\geq n) = \sigma(X)$ and we have $\{X \in A \} \in \sigma(X)$  by the definition of $\sigma(X)$ and therefore $P(X \in A) \in \{0,1\}$ by Kolmogorov. Does this work? - Ah, your way is pretty clear, thank you.

Comment: The concept of a degenerated $X$ has really no link whatsoever with Kolmogorovs 0-1 law. Thinking about Kolmogorov in this context is only troubling your mind.

Comment: I think there is some connection. Because one can prove that $X$ is independent of itself if and only if $P(X=c)=1$, i.e iff $X$ is degenerated. And only in this case I can apply Kolmogorov to the constant sequence $X=X_i$. But yeah, it is quite far-fetched, you are right.